# Can I remove one of two parallel house traps/clenouts and combine into one

Tags: plumbing

[image]

Currently I have two traps side by side before it goes out to the city sewer, but since I have to move some check valves around, I am limited in space.  Do I need both traps/cleanouts, or can I just consolidate to a single trap/cleanout like in the 2nd drawing if the cleanout is close to the y branch before it?